# What is causing the file upload limit issue in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm reading this line in Linux. However, when I'm echoing this in the browser, nothing shows up. Is there something wrong with how I used the echo line?

```
// relevant code snippets
$mypic = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['upload']['type'];

/*$finfo=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type=finfo_file($finfo,$temp);
finfo_close($finfo);*/

echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);
echo $mypic."<br />";
echo $type."<br />";
echo $_FILES['upload']['error']."<br />";
echo var_dump($type)."<br />";
```

If you suspect something is wrong with how I'm handling file inputs in another file, I've included that php file in [this link](https://gist.github.com/aa70d1d4fee856ac3e86).

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insert.php">

Name: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="15" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15" /><br />
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="cpassword" maxlength="15" /><br />

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000">
Choose your picture: <input type="file" name="upload"><p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /><br />

<p>
<center><h3><?php include("links.php"); ?></h3></center>

</form>
```

Here is the printout that I'm seeing:

> Array (
>       [upload] => Array
>           (
>               [name] => protest.jpg
>               [type] => 
>               [tmp_name] => 
>               [error] => 2
>               [size] => 0
>           )
>
> ) protest.jpg
>
> 2 string(0) ""

------------------Update as of 9:40 p.m. May 5, 2012-------------------------

I tried an icon and found no problems other than permissions settings (I think I can solve this on my own for the time being). However, I'm still stuck on setting the file size. I followed Peter Stuart's instructions and got the following printout:

[image]

Apparently, the file size limits in these two settings are more than enough to handle the original images I had (which are under 200 kb). I don't know what more I can do in this case.

Comment: Have you tried checking $_FILES['upload']['error']; ?

Comment: ...or `var_dump($_FILES);`...?

Comment: To the page, so you can see what's inside the array.

Comment: Put this at the top of your page: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);`  Add what it outputs to the question if you still aren't sure what the issue is.

Comment: I don't want to post an answer as it might not help (plus I have had a few beers lol). I would maybe check your upload file limit if you are trying to upload the image file.

Comment: @PeterStuart - you nailed it. Error 2 = max upload size exceeded.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the max upload size limit. I'm trying to figure out how I can solve this issue.

Comment: I have added a more detailed answer. Give it a go and see if that helps :) As Anthony says, I am pretty sure error 2 is a php upload file size limit. If it doesn't work I will keep thinking of a solution :)

Comment: @PeterStuart: It's about file size limits. I'm still having trouble going about solving it. I've updated some information in my question statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file type is empty for the same reason that the filesize is 0 and the error is 2.

From [Error Messages Explained](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

You have your max size set to `10000`, which is in bytes, so that's roughly 10Kb.  If it's a photo taken on any modern digital cam (over 4mgpx)  it will probably need to be at least ten times that size. Just leave out the max size for now until you get a rough average of the image size people are submitting. PHP has a max upload size of its own to avoid tying up the line for too long.

To avoid issues like this in the future (not knowing if the file upload was successul), you probably want to wrap your code in something like:

```
$upload_error[0] = "AOK";
$upload_error[1] = "Server says: File too big!";
$upload_error[2] = "Browser says: File too big!";
$upload_error[3] = "File upload didn't finish.";
$upload_error[4] = "Ummm.... You forgot the file.";
$upload_error[6] = "Oops.  Webmaster needs to fix something.";
$upload_error[7] = "Server says: I'm stuffed. Email webmaster.";
$upload_error[8] = "Server says: Not gonna do it.  Webmaster needs to fix something.";


if($_FILES['upload']['error'] == 0) {
   //do your thing and move it to the database.
} else {
    $error_num = $_FILES['upload']['error'];
    echo $upload_error[$error_num];
}
```

Comment: I've tried setting that size to `100000000` and I'm still seeing problems.

Comment: Did you place the 'M' at the end of your value. For example '100000M'? I would also recommend something like 5M, that way you don't get any suspicious files being uploaded.

Comment: Also in my answer I used upload_max_filesize.

Comment: @Anthony: I didn't downvote you. Just trying to digest what's going on.

Comment: Well someone did, and that's a hot button for me when I know I've spent 20 minutes to write out a detailed solution. Sorry.  The bottom line for your issue is: 1) Error Handling: if you're getting an error (other than 0), let the user know and stop that path in the code. then pull up the error list and see what's up. 2) debugging: if the issue is with max_file_size, turn it off to see if the problem is solved, *then* tweak later. You'll waste your day bumping up that number and retrying when you can just comment it out and see if it's even the problem at all.

Comment: Well Anthony, with no hard feelings intended, don't read someone else's comment and use it as your own answer (like mine). And don't accuse other users when downvotes are anonymous.

Comment: @PeterStuart - Glad there are no hard feelings. For the record, I posted the answer before I saw your comment. But I have been known to post comments as answers in my day, only if I thought it would help the OP more.  In this case, I was writing while you were commenting, it happens.  As for downvotes and accusations, I've posted a few really time-consuming and (IMHO) damn good answers in the past few days with not even a +1, so when this one went from 1 to 0, the sting may have been the last straw.  I knew as soon as I submitted it I'd be eating my words (as I am now). PeaceLoveDope.

Comment: As I said  no hard feelings,  it isn't about who answered what firs anyway, I tried to change my vote back up but its locked,  at the end of the day it is about @stanigator getting his problem solved,  any luck with that mate?

Comment: @stanigator - Indeed, have you tried a tiny file like the icon image I  commented in Peter's answer?

Comment: Hey all, just tried. See my update in the question. Btw, I voted up both your answers.

Comment: Did the small file work? Honestly, until the HTML5 File API is fully deployed (by which I mean, we officially stop caring about IE7, etc), I wouldn't even bother with setting browser-side file parameters (unless you are like me and like to make things future-ready while also discouraging users to stay on IE).  With the File API, you could set the file size, the type, and have the js return errors before PHP has to get involved.  Having said that, screw IE, you should really read up on and get into the habit of using the File API:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

Answer (score 1):

I would check your PHP upload size limit in your PHP ini file. It can cause adverse problems :)

If you create or go into your php.ini file and make sure the settings are as follows:

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M

post_max_size = 5M
```

Comment: I guess I would need to locate my php ini file somewhere, perhaps on my server?

Comment: Yes this is where you set your PHP ini file. If you can't find it you can contact your host for help. You can try creating a file called "php.ini" in your server root? Also if you create a file called phpinfo.php and insert the follow code : "<?php phpinfo(); ?>". When you load that php file it will tell you the upload_max_filesize and the post_max_size values.

Comment: @stanigator - Dude, have you tried just uploading a really small file (like this one : http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico ) and seeing if the problem persists?

Comment: @PeterStuart - uploads that exceed the server-set limit actually throw an Error 1. I was surprised to learn they had distinct errors for client-set limit vs server-set limit.

Comment: I am just answering this based on past problems I have had myself. I didn't know one of these errors was based on the client side.  Either way it doesn't matter. I just posted both INI settings because they are both common issues with PHP users.  Once we find the post_max_size this could help us solve this issue!

Comment: I tried your modification. Original settings looked fine (see my screenshot in problem statement). Both methods didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The order of settings are also matter, and it should be like

```
upload_max_filesize = 5M
post_max_size = 5M
```

And I always got maximum size error when `post_max_size` place before  `upload_max_filesize`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has 7 years but I stopped with it without finding a clear procedure to understand it. This is How I controlled it:

The sintom was that I could upload SMALL images (less than 2MB) BUT not bigger than 2MB. It's important to identify perfectly the ERROR. In this case "UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:" The sintom in the DEBUG was that ***$_FILES["image"]["type"] = ""***, (ridiculous) and I knew that was a .JPG image for sure.

SOLUTION: Using XAMPP, STOP it. Configure php.ini, go to "upload_max_filesize=2M" which means that the file you try to upload has a limit of 2 Megabytes, So you Will change it to (for example) 3M. After that, I started again XAMPP, and proceeded to upload an image of 2.5 MB, and was successful.

Im sorry but my status can't show images of configuration in this comment.